# Get the total difference between two dates into milliseconds php

Tags: php, datetime

actually I would like to know the way to convert the total difference between two different dates into milliseconds

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
 require_once('connect.php');

 $query="select * from fixture_list";
 $result=array();
 if($res= mysqli_query($con,$query)){
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

 $target=new DateTime($row['matchTime']);
 $now=new DateTime;
 $diff=$target->diff($now);
 if($target>$now){
 $timeLeft= $diff->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes,%s seconds to go');
 }
 else{
 $timeLeft= $diff->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds too 
 late bru');
 }  
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

my input format is: 'y:m:d h:m:s'
here the code works perfectly fine and it returns me the right result but I want the total difference in millisecods, please help me with this

Comment: If your input format doesn't include milliseconds how do you expect the output to include milliseconds? I mean you could just always put `, 0 ms` on any result, but why.

Comment: Actually I have a function in Java which needs milliseconds to work so I want the total difference of the given dates in milliseconds only, I don't have to set the milliseconds in my input , what I really want is that if suppose the output is 2 days,3 hours, 4 minutes then in that case I would like it to be converted into milliseconds

Comment: I hope you get me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First simplify your formatting:

```
$timeLeft= $diff->format('%a:%h:%i:%s');
```

then use some math

```
function toMs($duration){
        return (count($x=explode(':',$duration))==4?($x[0]*86400+$x[1]*3600+$x[2]*60+$x[3])*1000:false);
    }
```

eg:

```
  $duration_to_convert="2:3:4:20";
    var_dump(toMs($duration_to_convert));
```

output:

```
int(183860000)
```

**The logic is the same if you have century,years ,millenium or milliseconds in your duration** ...you will just need to alter a little the function...

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare toMs() (previously declared in /something/public_html/judgement_files/times.php:22) in /something/home/u181207488/public_html/judgement_files/times.php on line 22

Comment: i tried to search about this on internet and it says that the function is being included more than once but i have only used it once in my file like this    function toMs($duration){
       return (count($x=explode(':',$duration))==4?($x[0]*86400+$x[1]*3600+$x[2]*60+$x[3])*1000:false);
    }
 
echo toMs($timeLeft);

Comment: it is simple this function already exists in this file 'times.php'. If you have access then open it and check the prototype of this function .Maybe you could use it to convert to milliseconds.However if you don't know how to do so just rename my actual function to ToMilliseconds an use this new name.

Comment: It worked very fine dude, thanks for the help, one of the reasons I love the internet and sharing as you are sitting somewhere on the planet and helping me out here..cheers and good day.